# Displaying content outside the website's root directory when a user visits the website

Tags: php, redirect

A website that I work on has many directories that are each websites of their own. The idea is that when someone visits the website like this: `http://www.foo.com/bar` that the `index.html` / `index.php` for each `bar` (and whatever other files are needed to display it) are shown to a client.

The main website (`foo.com`) has its root directory in the `/www/...` path. The files for the main website are all at the website's root directory.

At the moment all of the `bar` directories are in the `/docs/...` path which is not normally accessible by visiting the website. However, there are symbolic links at the website's root directory for each `bar` that go to the appropriate `/docs/...` path.

Although this works, I would prefer not to have a symbolic link for each `bar` in the website's root directory.

What I would prefer to do is have a PHP script (or another kind of script if necessary) that determines if some `bar` exists in the `/docs/...` path and if it does display that to a client without all the symbolic links.

Is this possible and if so is it possible to do without making the URL appear to be different to a visiting client?

Comment: wouldn't a little restructuring and file moving be a better approach?

Comment: There is enough space for each `bar` where they are currently located and the lab would prefer that they stay where they are. The change would be to make web development easier for future students working on the website

Comment: i would then us an Apache Alias `Alias /foo /bar ` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Comment: I'll look into what those are, thanks

Comment: much like a symbolic link, just for the apache servre only

Comment: @Dagon, it turned out to be what was needed, thanks again

Comment: I have made it in to an answer, you can check if you like ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache alias is the answer, its much like a symbolic link allowing Apache to access directories outside of the web root as if they were inside the webroot

`Alias /foo /bar`

[Alias Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)